# Heroku App Crashed

Tags: crash, heroku, push, slug

I'm trying to figure out why my app crashed, my slug size is very large 54mb but on my computer the folder size is like 3mb, here is my log file: (Of course rails server runs perfectly fine, but can't figure out the heroku problem)

```
2011-11-12T20:40:08+00:00 heroku[rake.2]: State changed from created to starting
2011-11-12T20:40:29+00:00 app[rake.2]: Awaiting client
2011-11-12T20:40:30+00:00 heroku[rake.2]: State changed from starting to up
2011-11-12T20:40:35+00:00 heroku[rake.2]: Process exited
2011-11-12T20:40:36+00:00 heroku[rake.2]: State changed from up to complete
2011-11-12T20:42:04+00:00 heroku[rake.3]: State changed from created to starting
2011-11-12T20:42:19+00:00 app[rake.3]: Awaiting client
2011-11-12T20:42:19+00:00 app[rake.3]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2011-11-12T20:42:19+00:00 heroku[rake.3]: State changed from starting to up
2011-11-12T20:42:23+00:00 heroku[rake.3]: Process exited
2011-11-12T20:42:24+00:00 heroku[rake.3]: State changed from up to complete
2011-11-12T20:43:17+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-11-12T20:43:17+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-11-12T20:43:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 28660 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:71:in `rescue in establish_connection': Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (RuntimeError)
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:68:in `establish_connection'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:67:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `eval'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `new'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `map'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `block in <main>'
2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-11-12T20:43:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-11-12T20:43:40+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET mazurgroup.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2011-11-12T20:43:40+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [12/Nov/2011:12:43:40 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome

2011-11-12T20:43:40+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET mazurgroup.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2011-11-12T20:43:40+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [12/Nov/2011:12:43:40 -0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" mazurgroup.heroku.com
2011-11-12T20:44:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-11-12T20:44:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-11-12T20:44:21+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 10810 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:71:in `rescue in establish_connection': Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (RuntimeError)
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:68:in `establish_connection'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:67:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `eval'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `new'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `map'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `block in <main>'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<main>'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2011-11-12T20:44:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-11-12T20:44:26+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

take a deeper look in your logfile

> 2011-11-12T20:43:37+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:71:in `rescue in establish_connection': Please install the postgresql
>   adapter:`gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part
>   of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (RuntimeError)

Is the cause of your problem.

Heroku provide PostgreSql - consequently you need to add the pg gem to your Gemfile - presuming you're using sqlite3 presently for development

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

rebundle, commit and repush to Heroku and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks - I seem to be having a lot of heroku push errors, but at least that fixed problems for the time been.

Comment: Looking into `heroku logs` deeper helped me in another issue.